# Уникальные свойства и настройки темы Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, настройки

Установил тему Wordpress зи репозитория - Newses. У этой темы есть свои внутренние свойства и настройки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно мое свойство или настройку поместить в админку Wordpress (в Настройках сайта)? (к примеру в сайте secondwpsite в шапке сайта указывается дата и время, а также справа иконки соц. сетей (см. Настройки в левом столбце на скриншоте - `Скрыть/Показать дату, Скрыть/Показать время`  и т.д.) - наподобие этого как задать свои настройки)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Каким образом можно мое свойство или настройку поместить в админку
> Wordpress

Эти настройки называются "кастомайзер" (Customize). Для работы с ними существует [Customize API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/)

Ну и напомню, что любую кастомизацию нужно делать через [механизм дочерних тем](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/). А для облегчения правильного создания тем и копирования настроек из родительской рекомендую использовать специальные плагины (например [CTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/)), которые можно удалить после создания дочки.